# How to convert all numeric columns to intervals in R

Tags: r, dataframe, c5.0

I have a dataframe from 840 columns that I read from a .sav file. I convert all columns to factors using `data <- haven::as_factor(data)`

This is an example, data just after read the file and without convert to factor:

| tenureType | localityType | monthlyRent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 200 |
| 1 | 2 | 140 |
| 1 | 3 | 500 |
| 2 | 2 | 100 |
| 1 | 3 | 700 |
| 2 | 3 | 20 |

After `data <- haven::as_factor(data)`:

| tenureType | localityType | monthlyRent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Full ownership | Rural | 200 |
| Full ownership | Urban | 140 |
| Full ownership | Camp | 500 |
| For free | Urban | 100 |
| Full ownership | Camp | 700 |
| For free | Camp | 20 |

I have to convert the data to its labels as I want to make some processes on the texts.

I want to build a decision tree using `C50` library, so I want to convert all columns that their values (as factor) is a numeric -- like monthlyRent -- to factor of intervals

I want the data to be for example like this:

| tenureType | localityType | monthlyRent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Full ownership | Rural | 156-292 |
| Full ownership | Urban | 20-156 |
| Full ownership | Camp | 428 - 564 |
| For free | Urban | 20-156 |
| Full ownership | Camp | 564 - 700 |
| For free | Camp | 20-156 |

- I need each numeric column to be converted to 5 categories
- The intervals calculated by: `( max - min ) / 5`

In the above sample: (700 - 20 ) / 5 = 136.
Intervals are: [20-156], [156-292], [292-428], [428-564], [564-700].

I have 840 columns, so I don't know the columns names, I want the intervals to be dynamically, as such columns ranges are from 0 to 10 and others ranges 0 - 10000.

I want the best approach for this. If there is better approach than intervals calculated by `( max - min ) / 5` I'd like to know.

Comment: how will you select the intervals for each numeric column? i.e. where is the information that suggest 0-210, 210-600, 600-900 is the set of intervals for `monthlyRent`?

Comment: the intervals is just an example, I dont have an idea how the intervals will be. but I want it to be dynamically. I'm asking for the best approach for this

Comment: The sample data don't give any indication at all how to figure interval. You have two "Full ownership Camp" and they have different intervals. What is that based on?

Comment: I have edited the question and clarified this point. @langtang

Comment: @JohnPolo I have edited the question and clarified this point.

Comment: You can probably do something like this: `library(dplyr); mutate(df, across(where(is.numeric),cut,breaks=5))`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `mutate(across())` from the `dplyr` package, applying `cut()` with `breaks=5` to each of the numeric columns:

```
mutate(df, across(where(is.numeric),cut,breaks=5))
```

Output:

```
      tenureType localityType monthlyRent
1 Full ownership        Rural   (156,292]
2 Full ownership        Urban  (19.3,156]
3 Full ownership         Camp   (428,564]
4       For free        Urban  (19.3,156]
5 Full ownership         Camp   (564,701]
6       For free         Camp  (19.3,156]
```

Input

```
df = structure(list(tenureType = c("Full ownership", "Full ownership", 
                              "Full ownership", "For free", "Full ownership", "For free"), 
               localityType = c("Rural", "Urban", "Camp", "Urban", "Camp", 
                                "Camp"), monthlyRent = c(200L, 140L, 500L, 100L, 700L, 20L
                                )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```